# Mockito static mock with springwebflux flatmap

Tags: mockito, spring-webflux, static-methods

when testing webflux methods, mockito is not working properly. Basically i want to mock a static method which returns currentUserId. It works in the webflux chain before flatMap, but fails to work after flatmap.

Below code is working

```
@Test
    public void test0() {
        MockedStatic<SecurityUtils> securityUtilsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
        securityUtilsMockedStatic.when(SecurityUtils::getCurrentUserId).thenReturn(Mono.just("test"));

        Mono<ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>> testSource = Mono.just("something...")
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()))
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()))
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()));

        StepVerifier.create(testSource)
            .assertNext(next -> {
                String createdRecordId = extractId(next);
                Assertions.assertThat(createdRecordId).isNotBlank();
            })
            .verifyComplete();
    }
```

THIS IS NOT WORKING

```
@Test
    public void test2() {
        MockedStatic<SecurityUtils> securityUtilsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
        securityUtilsMockedStatic.when(SecurityUtils::getCurrentUserId).thenReturn(Mono.just("test"));

        Mono<ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>> testSource = Mono.just("something...")
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()))
            .flatMap(a -> reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord())) // mock is not working
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()));

        StepVerifier.create(testSource)
            .assertNext(next -> {
                String createdRecordId = extractId(next);
                Assertions.assertThat(createdRecordId).isNotBlank();
            })
            .verifyComplete();
    }
```

static method for reference

```
    public static Mono<String> getCurrentUserId() {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .map(SecurityUtils::extractPrincipal)
            .switchIfEmpty(ExceptionUtil.generateExceptionAsMono(SecurityExceptionEnum.PRINCIPAL_NOT_FOUND));
    }
```

Comment: Update: Figured the root cause (still exploring the solution) : Mockito uses Thread Local Context to store "static mock" object, with flatmap, the thread changes and hence the static mock object isn't available.

Answer (score 3):

The problem does not lie in flatmap - you are using `mockStatic` incorrectly.

`MockedStatic` interface extends `AutoCloseable`, and it needs to be closed after each test. If you don't do that, each test will pass when run in isolation, but will fail with self-explanatory message

```
For your_package.SecurityUtils, static mocking is already registered in the current thread
```

The most elegant way to close an AutoCloseable object is a try-with-resources block:

```java
@Test
public void test0() {
    try (MockedStatic<SecurityUtils> securityUtilsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class)) {
        securityUtilsMockedStatic.when(SecurityUtils::getCurrentUserId).thenReturn(Mono.just("test"));

        Mono<ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>> testSource = Mono.just("something...")
                .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()))
                .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()))
                .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()));

        StepVerifier.create(testSource)
                .assertNext(next -> {
                    String createdRecordId = extractId(next);
                    Assertions.assertThat(createdRecordId).isNotBlank();
                })
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can set the scheduler on your test:

- on the initial Mono
- on the Mono returned by flatMap (it have its own scheduler set. This scheduler won’t be overriden by any of the publishOn or subscribeOn method of the parent stream, but by default, it will run on the same scheduler as the parent. See [[Reactor Java #4] How to take control over the execution of Mono and Flux ?](https://medium.com/@cheron.antoine/reactor-java-4-how-to-take-control-over-the-execution-of-mono-and-flux-ead31dc066))

By setting the scheduler to `immediate` you will force the callbacks to be executed on the test worker thread.

```java
Mono<ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue>> testSource = Mono.just("something...")
            .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()))
            .flatMap(a -> reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord())
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.immediate())) // mock is not working
            .then(reactionResource.create(getRandomRecord()));
```

Comment: Tried this, not working. For me, they aren't working even when run in isolation. I figured the root cause, but not the solution yet. Root cause is: mockito stores "static mock" object in ThreadLocal context, and with flatmap, the thread changes (a different thread is assigned for the task). Hence, upon flatmap, the mocked static class is not present.